# PHP Accessing one array from class

Tags: php

I'm trying to access a single value of an array, I can't seem to get it right. This is the code:

```
    $socialCounts = new socialNetworkShareCount(array(
    'url' => 'http://facebook.com/',
    'facebook' => true,
    'buffer' => true,
    'pinterest' => true,
    'linkedin' => true,
    'google' => true
));

 print_r($socialCounts->getShareCounts());
```

Which Returns the following:

```
{"facebookshares":52132062,"facebooklikes":0,"pinterestshares":243942,"linkedinshares":4708,"googleplusones":0,"buffershares":207477,"total":52588189}
```

**How can I access the vaule of each individual Item? For example, if I'd like to echo the facebook shares value.**

And this is the full class if you need:

```
class socialNetworkShareCount{

    public $shareUrl;
    public $socialCounts = array();
    public $facebookShareCount = 0;
    public $facebookLikeCount = 0;
    public $twitterShareCount = 0;
    public $bufferShareCount = 0;
    public $pinterestShareCount = 0;
    public $linkedInShareCount = 0;
    public $googlePlusOnesCount = 0;


    public function __construct($options){

        if(is_array($options)){
            if(array_key_exists('url', $options) && $options['url'] != ''){
                $this->shareUrl = $options['url'];
            }else{
                die('URL must be set in constructor parameter array!');
            }

            // Get Facebook Shares and Likes
            if(array_key_exists('facebook', $options)){
                $this->getFacebookShares();
                $this->getFacebookLikes();
            }

            // Get Twitter Shares
            if(array_key_exists('twitter', $options)){
                $this->getTwitterShares();
            }

            // Get Twitter Shares
            if(array_key_exists('pinterest', $options)){
                $this->getPinterestShares();
            }

            // Get Twitter Shares
            if(array_key_exists('linkedin', $options)){
                $this->getLinkedInShares();
            }

            // Get Twitter Shares
            if(array_key_exists('google', $options)){
                $this->getGooglePlusOnes();
            }

            // Get Buffer Shares
            if(array_key_exists('buffer', $options)){
                $this->getBufferShares();
            }

        }elseif(is_string($options) && $options != ''){
            $this->shareUrl = $options;

            // Get all Social Network share counts if they are not set individually in the options
            $this->getFacebookShares();
            $this->getFacebookLikes();
            $this->getTwitterShares();
            $this->getPinterestShares();
            $this->getLinkedInShares();
            $this->getGooglePlusOnes();
            $this->getBufferShares();

        }else{
            die('URL must be set in constructor parameter!');
        }
    }


    public function getShareCounts(){
        $totalShares = $this->getTotalShareCount($this->socialCounts);
        $this->socialCounts['total'] = $totalShares;




        return json_encode($this->socialCounts);
    }

    public function getTotalShareCount(array $shareCountsArray){
        return array_sum($shareCountsArray);
    }


    public function getFacebookShares(){
        $api = file_get_contents( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . $this->shareUrl );
        $count = json_decode( $api );
        if(isset($count->shares) && $count->shares != '0'){
            $this->facebookShareCount = $count->shares;
        }
        $this->socialCounts['facebookshares'] = $this->facebookShareCount;
        return $this->facebookShareCount;
    }

    public function getFacebookLikes(){
        $api = file_get_contents( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . $this->shareUrl );
        $count = json_decode( $api );
        if(isset($count->likes) && $count->likes != '0'){
            $this->facebookLikeCount = $count->likes;
        }
        $this->socialCounts['facebooklikes'] = $this->facebookLikeCount;
        return $this->facebookLikeCount;
    }

    public function getTwitterShares(){
        $api = file_get_contents( 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/urls/count.json?url=' . $this->shareUrl );
        $count = json_decode( $api );
        if(isset($count->count) && $count->count != '0'){
            $this->twitterShareCount = $count->count;
        }
        $this->socialCounts['twittershares'] = $this->twitterShareCount;
        return $this->twitterShareCount;
    }


    public function getBufferShares(){
        $api = file_get_contents( 'https://api.bufferapp.com/1/links/shares.json?url=' . $this->shareUrl );
        $count = json_decode( $api );
        if(isset($count->shares) && $count->shares != '0'){
            $this->bufferShareCount = $count->shares;
        }
        $this->socialCounts['buffershares'] = $this->bufferShareCount;
        return $this->bufferShareCount;
    }


    public function getPinterestShares(){
        $api = file_get_contents( 'http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback%20&url=' . $this->shareUrl );
         $body = preg_replace( '/^receiveCount\((.*)\)$/', '\\1', $api );
         $count = json_decode( $body );
         if(isset($count->count) && $count->count != '0'){
            $this->pinterestShareCount = $count->count;
         }
         $this->socialCounts['pinterestshares'] = $this->pinterestShareCount;
         return $this->pinterestShareCount;
    }


    public function getLinkedInShares(){
         $api = file_get_contents( 'https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=' . $this->shareUrl . '&format=json' );
        $count = json_decode( $api );
        if(isset($count->count) && $count->count != '0'){
            $this->linkedInShareCount = $count->count;
        }
        $this->socialCounts['linkedinshares'] = $this->linkedInShareCount;
        return $this->linkedInShareCount;
    }

    public function getGooglePlusOnes(){

        if(function_exists('curl_version')){

            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc" );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $this->shareUrl . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]' );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-type: application/json' ) );
            $curl_results = curl_exec( $curl );
            curl_close( $curl );
            $json = json_decode( $curl_results, true );
            $this->googlePlusOnesCount = intval( $json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'] );

        }else{

            $content = file_get_contents("https://plusone.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?url=".urlencode($_GET['url'])."&count=true");
            $doc = new DOMdocument();
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $doc->loadHTML($content);
            $doc->saveHTML();
            $num = $doc->getElementById('aggregateCount')->textContent;

            if($num){
                $this->googlePlusOnesCount = intval($num);
            }
        }

        $this->socialCounts['googleplusones'] = $this->googlePlusOnesCount;
        return $this->googlePlusOnesCount;
    }}
```

Comment: That's JSON data. You can do this: `$parsedArray = json_decode($socialCounts->getShareCounts());` and that will give you an associative array where you'll be able to access the data like this, for example: `$parsedArray['facebookshares']`. Alternatively, you can do that inside the class function before you return the JSON data and return associative array instead.

Comment: @AleksandarBencun Check out the class. `getShareCount()` intentionally wraps results in `json_encode()`. There's no point in using it since the individual results are already public.

Comment: Oh, that's true. Well, in that case he might as well first analyze the inner workings of the class. That's why I added this as a comment, instead of an answer, it's a quick and dirty solution to his question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the class definition, you don't need to invoke `getShareCounts()`. It looks like that method is perhaps used to provide some lower end API functionality. I don't think it's meant for your use case.

All of the below public variables are accessible and filled in once the [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) has run.

```
public $facebookShareCount = 0;
public $facebookLikeCount = 0;
public $twitterShareCount = 0;
public $bufferShareCount = 0;
public $pinterestShareCount = 0;
public $linkedInShareCount = 0;
public $googlePlusOnesCount = 0;
```

So you can access them like so:

```
$socialCounts = new socialNetworkShareCount(array(
    'url' => 'http://facebook.com/',
    'facebook' => true,
    'buffer' => true,
    'pinterest' => true,
    'linkedin' => true,
    'google' => true
));

print_r($socialCounts->facebookShareCount); // facebook shares
print_r($socialCounts->facebookLikeCount); // facebook likes
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorted. Makes sense now

Comment: @ClaudioSantos Thanks for the update! If this solution worked for you, please feel free to accept the answer. This will let others know so they do not continue providing unnecessary answers. :) [You can accept a given answer by selecting the checkbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

> mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth
>   = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Since your json is an object, `json_decode($yourparam)` will return an [stdClass](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting) by default, which will have public members. Since you would like to use an associated `array` instead, you need to call something like `json_decode($yourparam, true)`, which will return an associated `array`, since the second parameter is a boolean value determined by your intention whether you want an associated array as result, default value being `false`.